# ETL present data without the schedule interval delay while not breaking the Catchup

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that need to be trigger every Tuesday and Friday (for context, purpose of the DAG is basically ETL data published only twice a week on Tuesday and Friday)

This DAG need to Catchup the past.

I use the {{ execution_date }} in many operator parameter (for API call parameter, in storage name for keeping copy of raw data, ...)

The Catchup works well, my issue is with the present.

Because of the schedule interval, every Friday it will ETL the data of previous Tuesday (use execution_date for API call parameter) and every Tuesday it will ETL the data of previous Friday.

What I need is that the Tuesday run get data of this Tuesday and not the previous Friday.

I think about using start_date instead of execution_date for API call but in this case the Catchup will not work as expected.

I don't find any pretty solution where Catchup work well and present data are processed without the schedule interval delay...

Any idea ?

**EDIT Based on andscoop answer:**

Best solution is to use next_execution_date instead of execution_date

Comment: I answered to the best of my abilities with the information provided, but please provide a code snippet and I may be able to further help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=catchup#backfill-and-catchup) will not prevent the most current DAG from running. It only determines whether or not previous un-run DAGs will run to "catchup".

There is no delay per-se, what you are seeing is that the reported execution date is only showing the last completed schedule interval.

You will want to look into Airflow [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=macro#macros) to template the exact timestamp you need.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. By using the execution_date to extract the data, the DAG run on Friday will extract the data from Tuesday (As the execution_date of the DAG run on Friday will be equal to previous Tuesday). If I use start_date instead of execution_date to extract data the Catchup will not work anymore as for any past interval it will use the same date

Comment: I believe I understand clearly, the link I posted to airflow macros provides several other alternatives to `execution_date` that will most likely suit your needs.

Please look at `next_execution_date` or `previous_execution_date` depending on your exact needs.

If these do not fit those needs, you will want to look into writing a custom macro. 

Code examples would help me provide a more exact answer.

Comment: You right, next_execution_date could be an interesting solution as it will ensure that DAG run on Friday will get the data of Friday and will not broke the Catchup too. Thanks